# Convert string into Array by comma separated

Tags: jquery, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

The following are the parameters pass through ajax call to rails controller

```
Parameters: {"selectedpos"=>"[\"55f188e9f8e6c2616f00006e\",\"55f17bc5f8e6c2616f00004a\"]", "id"=>"55f24b81f8e6c214d5000014", "_"=>"1441942399695"}
```

Ajax Call:

```
var purchaseorders = $('#purchaseorders option:selected');
    var selectedpos = [];
    $(purchaseorders).each(function(index, brand){
        selectedpos.push($(this).val());
    });
    $.ajax({
      url: '/getpurchaseorder_data' ,
        type: "GET",
          data: { selectedpos:JSON.stringify(selectedpos), id: '<%= @invoice._id %>'},
          dataType: 'script'
    });
```

In rails controller the selectedpos treated as string now a need to convert these string into array of po ids.

Comment: Why are you manually `JSON.stringify(selectedpos)` in your JavaScript?

Comment: In addition to muistooshort's comment: What happens if you don't `JSON.stringify` your array and instead pass `data: { selectedpos: selectedpos, id: '<%= @invoice._id %>' }`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the split function like that :

```
var str = "How are you doing today?";
var res = str.split(" ");
```

the result of res will be an array with the values:

How,are,you,doing,today?

in your case it's a comma instead of space

Answer (score 1):

As per your Question's title:

> Convert string into Array by comma separated

You can use **[String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#split-method)** method:

```
> string = "This,is,my,sample string"
> string.split(',')
#=> ["This", "is", "my", "sample string"]
```

Comment: > string = "[\"55f188e9f8e6c2616f00006e\",\"55f17bc5f8e6c2616f00004a\"]" this whole part is string the what we do..?